# Как правильно сгенерировать id пользователя в mongodb и node.js?

Tags: javascript, база-данных, node.js, mongodb, users

Всем доброго времени суток! Прошу помощи у опытных программистов! :)

Есть подобный код на node.js:

```
    static create_user(params, callback) {
    let user_document = {
        //user_id: ВОТ_ТУТ_НАДО_СГЕНЕРИТЬ_ID,
        fb_id:params.fb_id||false,
        vk_id:params.vk_id||false,
        first_name:params.first_name||false,
        last_name:params.last_name||false,
        city:params.city||false
    };
    users_collection.insert(user_document, (err, user_result)=> {
        console.log(user_document, user_result);
        callback(err, user_document);
    });
}
```

Конечно возвращает то что и ожидается. Но проблема, я не могу выдать пользователям id который генерит mongodb("_id" : ObjectId("57dfec32d1703f11ac9c4500")), это не удобно, не наглядно и не хочется палить какая база данных у меня стоит.

Все хочется пользоваться автоинкрементном, придумал уже несколько способов. Но как это сделать ПРАВИЛЬНО?

Answer (score 2):

```
       static auto_id(name, callback){
    mongo_db.collection('__counters').findAndModify(
        { _id: name },
        [],
        { $inc: { "inc": 1 } },
        { new: true , upsert:true},
        (err, response)=>{
            callback(response.value.inc);
        }
    );
}
```

Нашел только такое, "элегантное" решение

Answer (score 0):

Вот вам отличный модуль: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-autoincrement
Пример использования есть по ссылке.

Comment: Думаю этот вариант на столько же неудобный/удобный как и мой.